# Pushpin on a bing map control, polygon on the pushpin, why cannot click on my pushpin?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, bing-maps

I'm developing a WPF Application with the bing map control.

On my map, i added some pushpin.
I added a click event on my pushpin.

All is ok, i can click on my pushpin and the event is fire.

Now, i need to add some circles ( MapPolygon ) on the map.

When the circle is "on" a pushpin, my click event on my pushpin is not fire.

I need to have always the click event on the pushpin  ( an not on the circle).

For information, i draw my circles by MapPolygon directly by C#, and not by WPF.

Comment: Did you try to set `IsHitTestVisible` on your circles to `false`?

Comment: It sounds like you're placing your ellipses over top of the pushpin in the visual tree z-index. Which would explain why your click events for the pushpins are getting intercepted by the ellipses. You could either set your pushpins at a higher z-index or draw your ellipses before the pushpin for a lower place in the visual tree. Either way you'll need to ensure your pushpins are on top.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Didier, solution is :

Setting

```
IsHitTestVisible
```

to false on the circle !